# How does one calculate the values of LF1&2 and C93?

Tags: filter, inductor, low-pass

I am learning about USB circuitry and one of the example schematics uses this lc low pass filter. I want to understand where these values came from? Thanks in advance. [Link to article](https://www.acmesystems.it/pcb_usb)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl; dr: The designers didn’t calculate anything really. They likely just followed another design.

The LF1/LF2 filter elements are ferrite beads. They suppress common-mode noise coming from the board. This helps the board pass EMC / EMI testing.

Ferrite beads are rated in impedance at a given frequency, rather than inductance. In this case, they chose a 220 ohm @ 100 MHz ("LF221") as a standard value for a high-current bead. In general, you choose as large an impedance as you can in the size ferrite you need for your rated current.

C93 is a bulk bypass capacitor. 100uF is a standard recommended value for USB endpoint bulk decoupling.

Comment: thank you. How are you able to tell it is a 100MHz bead? Other than just experience, is there anything that specifically tells you?

Comment: It doesn’t mean it’s a ‘100Mhz bead’. It’s just that the test conditions for the bead specifies that frequency. The datasheet shows a complete curve out to 1GHz or more.

Comment: What makes a bead different from an inductor is its loss characteristic. It tends to convert more of the AC energy to heat than a plain inductor.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I read [here](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ferrite-beads-demystified.html)  that a good design guideline is to use beads at 20% of their rated DC current. Which suggests that I should be looking for a bead with about 750mA that is resistive at 1MHz? Have you heard about this?

Comment: At this point I will refer you to Murata’s selection guide, which will provide more details and suggestions for your application. See here: https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/emc/emifil/selectionguide

Comment: The BLM18P series (0603 size) is what I tend to use for this.

Comment: Thank you for that. I had picked the [BLM15EG221SN1](https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/productdetail.aspx?cate=luNoiseSupprFilteChipFerriBead&partno=BLM15EG221SN1%23) before seeing that. My thinking was that it would work since its rated 220 @ 1MHz for 700mA, but completely ignored the left panel.